# Automatically BCC outgoing emails out of domain email

Tags: email, automation

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14543641/2014043) question over at SO and was asked to come here.

I want to be able to Auto BCC (or even just CC, for that matter) any and all outgoing emails that go through all of my .com addresses.

ie. all outgoing emails from foo@ourdomain.com, bar@ourdomain.com and faz@ourdomain.com will auto BCC (or CC) admin@ourdomain.com.

Is this even possible? If it is, I think I'm Googling for the wrong keywords coz I'm getting nowhere.

Can anyone shed some light on this dark matter?

EDIT: I want to be able to do this on the server-side, if possible.

I will be getting a dedicated server for this, which will probably be running CentOS. I will have root access to the box.

Comment: clientDo you have admin access to the server? erver software? Are you connecting to an external smtp server? What client software are they using? We need more details to help

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know what details would be relevant to this issue. We already have the domain, but we don't have a server yet. This is why I'm asking ahead so I know what to look for when I get the VPS or Dedicated server.

Comment: There is some (old, inconclusive) discussion [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/servers/5755-bcc-within-sendmail.html). And [this one](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/copy-out.html) has some more detail - apparently, it's very easy with Postfix but quite difficult with Sendmail. More recent discussion [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-148924.html). But it all depends on which outgoing mail agent you end up using.

Comment: what MTA are you going to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways - the way I have done it on CentOs is to add a small utility:

[Sendmail automatic BCC utility - SnertSoft](http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-bcc/)

This will automatically add a new BCC recipient to each message based on your own rules.

You don't need anything special on the VPS - just download and install that utility and configure it for your specific email or all recipients per the link above

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, unfortunately it's way over my head and can't get it to work. Are there any tutorials out there for this? Google doesn't seem to have anything.

Comment: The instructions are here [link] (http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-bcc/#Installation) - they include a step by step process with all of the commands. All you need is just SSH access (standard) to your VPS

Comment: Yeah, that's the part that went over my head. Heh. I'll have to do some serious reading then. Thanks for the answer.